# Rewrite URL path in Azure Front Door - Error HTTP 404

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have the following FD routes as fictional examples:

- mysite.azurefd.net/app1 *--forwards-->* "app1.azurewebsites.net"
- mysite.azurefd.net/app2 *--forwards-->* "app2.azurewebsites.net"

However, Front Door is still sending the examples paths `/app1` and `/app2` and I get error `HTTP 404`.

Custom forwarding path is set like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Setting the match patterns like this solved my problem.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite

Answer (score -1):

This along with setting the Custom forward path under URL rewrite is very important to make it work.

[image]